# Visual studio Code Collapse panes

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone know of a keyboard shortcut to collapse all the panes in visual studio code? I've had a look in the keyboard shortcut settings and couldn't find anything and searching on google just returns visual studio results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the next update we will add a command to close all editors.

**Update**
With version 0.5.0 there is a new command to close all editors (`View: Close All Editors` from the command palette).

After this version we will have commands to collapse editors and restore them.

Comment: That's great news thanks. Is this a collapse all editors windows rather than close? ![like this](http://cl.ly/bkqB) where the editors aren't closed just collapsed

Comment: no the action will close all editors. do you want an action to collapse all editors?

Comment: Exactly a shortcut to collapse all editors other then the one your currently editing in. The default currently is when you open a new pane the split is 50/50 at the moment I have to grab the mouse and manually collapse the other editors (I know first world problem). It would be really nice to have a keyboard shortcut to do that.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I can look into it for the update after the next update. We are already too close to ship the update to include it there, sorry.

Answer (score 13):

I use:

**On Mac**

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to collapse the "left" panel (file explorer, ...)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to collapse the "bottom" panel (terminal, etc ...)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>  to collapse **both at once**

**On Windows**

Same shortcuts but with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> :

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to collapse the "left" panel (file explorer, ...)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to collapse the "bottom" panel (terminal, etc ...)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>  to collapse **both at once**

The shortcut is fairly easy to remember.

Comment: Oh I like CMD+B+J, but I usually just go into zen mode if I need to focus, then pop out when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar can be toggled with Ctrl+B (on Mac ⌘+B.)

Comment: thanks but after collapsing the editor panes not the sidebar